# Why can't I complete the type with the typedef?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Given an incomplete type in translation unit A:

```
struct Incomplete;

Incomplete* create_incomplete();
void destroy_incomplete(Incomplete*);
```

why can't I use it in another translation unit, by using `typedef`?

For example in translation unit B:

```
struct Unrelated
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

typedef Unrelated Incomplete;

Incomplete* create_incomplete()
{
    return new Incomplete();
}

void destroy_incomplete(Incomplete* arg)
{
    delete arg;
}
```

Comment: Because you've already declared `Incomplete` to be a type, not a type alias.

Comment: Ok, but I'm looking for an authoritative answer (based on standard quotes)

Comment: Oh wait, I didn't notice that you have these as separate translation units.  So my comment above may not hold...

Comment: You can’t possibly complete something that is declared in a different translation unit. Either you `#include` your first file in the second one and in this case you have everything happening in a single translation unit, or, if you don’t `#include` it, you just have a typedef and no incomplete types in unit B and an incomplete type (which you don’t complete because you don’t have to) in unit A.

Comment: @kirelagin You're right. I apologise for my sloppy wording, I'll fix the question in a minute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Incomplete` is a type, introduced by your declaration and you cannot have a typedef using the same name, refering to another type.

Your `struct Incomplete;` is a forward class declaration which inserts a class-name into the global scope (and introduces a new, yet incomplete type).

**§9/2**

> A class-name is inserted into the scope in which it is declared immediately after the class-name is seen.

**§9.1/2**

> A declaration consisting solely of class-key identifier; is either a redeclaration of the name in the current scope or a forward declaration of the identifier as a class name.

In order to use that name where a complete type is required, it must be defined.

**§3.2/4**

> Exactly one definition of a class is required in a translation unit if the class is used in a way that requires the class type to be complete.

A class ist defined using the class-specifier.

**§9/2**

> A class is considered defined after the closing brace of its class-specifier has been seen even though its member functions are in general not yet defined.

Your typedef is a declaration and does not define the class.

**§7.1.3/1**

> Declarations containing the decl-specifier typedef declare identifiers that can be used later for naming fundamental (3.9.1) or compound (3.9.2) types.

**§3.1/2**

> A declaration is a definition unless [...] it is a typedef declaration [...].

Whereas declarations in the same scope / declarative region are required to refer to the same entity.

**§3.3.1/4**

> Given a set of declarations in a single declarative region, each of which specifies the same unqualified name
>
> - they shall all refer to the same entity, or all refer to functions and function templates; [ ... ]

Your typedef declares `Incomplete` to refer to `Unrelated` whereas `struct Incomplete;` declares a type `Incomplete`.

**§7.1.3/6**

> In a given scope, a typedef specifier shall not be used to redefine the name of any type declared in that scope to refer to a different type.

*C++11*

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for (especially the "they shall all refer to the same entity" part).

Answer (score 2):

You can’t complete something that is declared in a *different translation unit*. Either you `#include` your first file in the second one and in this case you have everything happening in a single translation unit, or, if you don’t `#include` it, you just have a `typedef` and no incomplete types in unit B and an incomplete type (which you don’t ever complete because you don’t have to) in unit A.

And you can’t complete a class with a `typedef` in a single unit, because:

> **3.9.5.** A class that has been declared but *not defined*, or an array of unknown
>   size or of incomplete element type, is an incompletely-defined object
>   type. Incompletely-defined object types and the void types are
>   *incomplete types*.

> **3.9.2.** A declaration is a *definition* unless <…> it is a `typedef` declaration, <…>.

([N3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf); some emphases add by me.)

So, you can’t complete a class type with a `typedef` because a class type can be completed only by a *definition* and `typedef` declaration is not a definition.

Comment: I upvoted your answer because it helped me in understanding the issue.